# Shooting extra balls - Block breaker game bug (Unity 2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm making a block breaker game that the player can get extra balls and shoot those balls with the original one.

**Does anyone knows what is wrong?** If there is not enough information, just tell me and I can provide it here.

Thanks

=========== CHANGED THE CODE TO BE MORE CLEAN ===========

Created my own pool logic to get more control and created a ExtraBallManager.cs to handle only functions related to that.

Here is how it is now (also I figured out that I didn't have to use coroutine):

```
public class ExtraBallManager : MonoBehaviour
```

{

```
private Ball ballController;
private GameManager gameManager;
public float ballWaitTime;
private float ballWaitTimeSeconds;
public int numberOfExtraBalls;
public int numberOfBallsToFire;
public ObjectPool objectPool;
//public TextAlignment numberOfBallsText;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    ballController = FindObjectOfType<Ball>();
    gameManager = FindObjectOfType<GameManager>();
    ballWaitTimeSeconds = ballWaitTime;
    numberOfExtraBalls = 0;
    numberOfBallsToFire = 0;

}

void Update() {
    if(ballController.currentBallState == Ball.ballState.fire || ballController.currentBallState == Ball.ballState.wait){
        if(numberOfBallsToFire > 0){
            ballWaitTimeSeconds -= Time.deltaTime;
            if(ballWaitTimeSeconds <= 0){
                GameObject tempBall = objectPool.GetPooledObject("Temp Ball");
                if(tempBall != null){
                    tempBall.transform.position = ballController.ballLaunchPosition;
                    tempBall.SetActive(true);
                    //It seems the error occurs in here
                    //sometimes it just don't add this tempBall to the
                    //list
                    gameManager.ballsInScene.Add(tempBall);
                    tempBall.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = ballController.initialBallVelocity;
                    ballWaitTimeSeconds = ballWaitTime;
                    numberOfBallsToFire--;
                }
                ballWaitTimeSeconds = ballWaitTime;
            }
        }
    }

    if(ballController.currentBallState == Ball.ballState.endShot){
        numberOfBallsToFire = numberOfExtraBalls;
    }

}
```

}

My Ball.cs part where switch the Ball State:

```
   void Start()
{
    arrow.SetActive(false);
    currentBallState = ballState.aim;
    rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    ballTransform = GetComponent<Transform>();
    lineRenderer = arrow.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    gameManager = FindObjectOfType<GameManager>();
    stoppedPosition = transform.position;
    currentBallState = Ball.ballState.aim;
    gameManager.ballsInScene.Add(this.gameObject);

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    switch(currentBallState) {
        case ballState.aim:
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && gameObject.tag == "Ball"){
                MouseClicked();
            }
            if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) && gameObject.tag == "Ball"){
                MouseDragged();
            }
            if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && gameObject.tag == "Ball"){
                ReleaseMouse();
            }

            break;
        case ballState.fire:
            break;
        case ballState.wait:
            stoppedPosition = transform.position;
            /*
            if(gameManager.IsThereAnyExtraBallOnScene()){
                currentBallState = ballState.endShot;
            }*/

            if(gameManager.ballsInScene.Count == 1){
                currentBallState = Ball.ballState.endShot;
            }

            break;
        case ballState.endShot:
            for(int i = 0; i < gameManager.blocksInScene.Count; i++){
                if(gameManager.blocksInScene[i]){
                    gameManager.blocksInScene[i].GetComponent<BlockMovementController>().currentState = BlockMovementController.blockState.move;
                } 
            }
            gameManager.level += 1;
            gameManager.SpawnBlocks();
            currentBallState = ballState.aim;
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }



}
```

Comment: You mean the extraBallsPwrUpCount?

Comment: ok! its correct... did that to thrown all the extra balls the user got during the gameplay. The thing is that, everything works perfectly... but sometimes during the gameplay those extra balls just don't be added into this list. I'm trying a lot of different solutions, I also created a simple pool object for those extra balls... but the bug keep happening.

Comment: What want you to do with yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f); The value is not used...is it a thread wait?

Comment: Yes, when the extra balls hit the ground they are removed from the scene (and from this list). Then I despawn it from the pool also.

Comment: This WaitForSeconds(0.2f) is only to have a gap between each shot. So the next ball to be thrown will wais this amount, then set the velocity and thrown it at the same position the original one.